# System.Net.WebException when connecting a URL

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, webclient

I have a windows service running every 3 minutes. At the start, this service hits a static URL that which returns "success". We are using `WebClient.OpenRead(URL)` for getting the result.

This is working fine in most machines. In one particular machine I am getting the following exception:

```
 System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: 
  Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->   
   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: 
    The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

I moved this function alone to a separate exe and it was working fine. But when the same runs as a service, I am getting the mentioned exception. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you (temporarily) run the service under the same user account as the exe works under, does the service then work?

Comment: It is already running under the same account

Comment: Change your target framework into 4.8. Compile and retry. If OS is a W7 (I suspect yes) in the machine that have this problem should be installed also framework 4.8. Probably this resolve your issue.

Comment: Will install .NET 4.8 and update you. Currently the target framework is 4.5.2